# Indefinite integral $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + x^4}} \, dx $ involving $\mathrm{sgn}()$ function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How to solve integrals like 
$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + x^4}} \, dx $$
If we factor out $x^2$ from denominator it become 
$=\int \frac{x}{\left| x \right|} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} \, dx $ 
$=\int \mathrm{sgn}(x) \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} \, dx $ 
What to do next ?
can't we do this like 
$=\int \frac{x}{x} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} \, dx $ 
$=\int  \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} \, dx $ 
 it becomes an easy integral with substitution now.  
Is it wrong ?
So my quetion  is that can we write $\sqrt{x^2}$  as x in this case ?

Comment: It is right on $(0,+\infty)$ and wrong on $(-\infty,0)$ where a minus sign is missing.

Comment: Do the $x \geq 0$ and  $x \leq 0$ cases separately.

Comment: wolfram alpha says this $\frac{\sqrt{(x^2 + 1)}}{\mathrm sgn(x)} $ is the answer .Is this correct ? If yes then how wolfram alpha arrived there ? can I just assume $\mathrm sgn(x)$ as constant ?

Comment: It *is* constant on $(0,+\infty)$ and on $(-\infty,0).$

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.
The integrand is well defined on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$. This is the crucial point then. So how do you work with such cases?

You observe that indeed

$$\int \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+x^4}}\ \text{d}x = \int \dfrac{\vert x\vert }{x} \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ \text{d}x = \int \dfrac{\vert x\vert }{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ \text{d}x$$

The integrand is well defined in $0$ (indeed for example you can compute the integral from $-1$ to $+1$). Split into positive and negative $x$ and observe.

Consider also the integrand is an even function.

Eventually,

$$\int \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+x^4}}\ \text{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^2}}{x} + C \equiv \dfrac{\vert x\vert \sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} + C = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\text{sgn(x)}} + C = \sqrt{x^2+1}\ \text{sgn}(x) + C$$

Comment: @DavidK Oh, my bad indeed. Going to correct, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the sign function, integrate as follows
\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + x^4}}dx 
=\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + x^4}}{x^2}\overset{ibp}{dx}
- \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x^4}} dx
=\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + x^4}}{x}
\end{align}